# Seifert surface and crossing number

Tags: surfaces, knot-theory

i am sitting here with the problem of Seifert Surfaces. I know from a theorem that every knot does have a Seifert surface. We can also make a so called disc-and-band surface $F$ by gluing $v$ discs and $e$ bands together. Then we get $\chi(F)=v-e$ (this is a very simple fact). We can construct such a Seifert surface by the Seifert-algorithm such that we get the Seifert-discs. Then we can glue some bands to connect the discs. Then we want to conclude the following inequality:$$g(K)\leq\frac{c(K)}{2}$$ with $g(K)$ the genus of the knot $K$ and $c(K)$ the crossing-number. Can someone give a suggestion how to make such a estimate?! I can give the proof of the fact with $\chi(F)$ and also the inequality $u(K)\leq c(K)/2$ with u(K) the unknotting number. Can someone gibe a good proof?

Answer (score 0):

If you take the surface obtained by Seifert's algorithm on a diagram with the minimal number of crossings for a knot $K$. You can observe that it admits a natural polygonal decomposition from the Seifert disks. Say you have $S$ of them. You can decompose their boundary into arcs that are arcs of the knot diagram, and arcs that are the section of the Seifert surface that is covered by the crossing. In total, this gives you $2cr(K)$ arcs of the first kind, and $2cr(K)$ arcs of the second kind, which are then identified two by two, thus, $E=3cr(K)$. Finally, the number of vertices of the polygonal decomposition is also $2cr(K)=V$.

Then, $1-2g(K)=\chi(F)=S-E+V=S-cr(K)$. Since $S>0$, $1-S\le 0$, hence solving for $g(K)$ and substituting in the inequality yields $$g(K)\le \frac{cr(K)}{2}.$$